# When I try to Submit my repo on packagist.org, I get "undefined"

Tags: composer-php

The repo is [template-PHP-project](https://github.com/unixnut/template-PHP-project).  When I use the Submit function on [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/) I get a pop-up that just says "`undefined`".

Clearly there is something wrong with my `composer.json` but I don't know what.  (I can run **`composer update`** without errors.)  It contains the following:

```
{  
    "name": "unixnut/template-php-project",
    "description": "A self-contained project that uses the Composer autoloader to load class files",
    "license": "GPL",
    "authors": [
        {  
            "name": "Alastair Irvine",
            "email": "alastair@plug.org.au"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "include-path": ["app/include", "contrib"],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "XYZ\\": "app/classes/XYZ"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `composer validate` command.

I just validated your file locally, and the only error is about the license. Fix and check again.

```
$ composer validate
./composer.json is valid, but with a few warnings
See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md for details on the schema
License "GPL" is not a valid SPDX license identifier, see https://spdx.org/licenses/ if you use an open license.
If the software is closed-source, you may use "proprietary" as license.
```